# AMQP NodeJS Connection

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq, amqp

I have a Node application that will use RabbitMQ and I am using amqplib to access it. I understand that TCP/IP connections to RabbitMQ and expensive, channels are cheap so create one connection and then multiple channels.

What I am slightly confused about is how I rate that one connection that can be used across the application? Most tutorials seems to indicate that a connection is open for a purpose and then closed again only to be opened again when next required.

I would think that this would result in multiple connections if multiple users were attempting an action that required RabbitMQ access at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your users are only connected to your server which is different to each user is connected directly to rabbitmq. Then, server-side, you can keep only one connection to rabbitmq.

For that purpose, I would recommend to create a [module](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html) to keep track of your connection across your application.

Note that AMQP has a [heartbeat](https://www.rabbitmq.com/heartbeats.html) feature :

> AMQP 0-9-1 offers a heartbeat feature to ensure that the application layer promptly finds out about disrupted connections (and also completely unresponsive peers). Heartbeats also defend against certain network equipment which may terminate "idle" TCP connections.

By default, [amqplib's hearbeat](http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#connect) is set to 0 meaning no heartbeat.